# Throws statement doesn't consider inherited exception

Tags: java, exception, throws, checked-exceptions

I have 2 exceptions:

```
class MyException1 extends Exception {
 --
}

class MyException2 extends MyException1 {
--
}


function invokeValidation() throws MyException2 {

    obj1.method() // it throws MyException1
    obj2.method() // it throws MyException2
}
```

The above code says `unhandled exception type MyException1`,
even though `MyException2` extends `MyException1`. Why does it expect `MyException1` in the throws statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `obj1.method()` throws a `MyException1`, it may throw a sub-class of `MyException1` that is not `MyException2` (or a sub-class of `MyException2`). Therefore it's not enough to declare that `invokeValidation()` throws `MyException2`.

On the other hand, if you declare `invokeValidation() throws MyException1`, that would be sufficient, since any `MyException2` exception is also a `MyException1`.

Comment: It may be worth noting that it IS enough to say `throws MyException1`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may become clearer to you if you use more meaningful exception names, as your exception naming doesn't reflect the real purpose of the exception.

For example, suppose your `Exception1` is now `IOException`. It indicates that there is some input-output problem. And your extending exception, instead of `Exception2` is now called `FileNotFoundException`. It indicates a specific input-output error - that a file was not found.

So, as you see, a `FileNotFoundException` *is a* kind of `IOException`. That's the relationship the word `extends` defines.

Now imagine if your method was declared:

```
public void invokeValidation() throws FileNotFoundException {

    obj1.method(); // it throws IOException
    obj2.method(); // it throws FileNotfoundException
}
```

So, you said "my method throws a `FileNotFoundException`". The compiler knows that if it runs into this particular Exception, it should throw it up to to the caller. But `obj1` may be throwing an `IOException`. It could be an exception that indicates that there is no space on disk. Or that there is a bad block. Or that the file was closed abruptly. It could be lots of things. An `IOException` is *not* a `FileNotFoundException`. Therefore, the compiler doesn't have anything to do with it, and it tells you that this is an unhandled exception.

But if your method was declared:

```
public void invokeValidation() throws IOException {

    obj1.method(); // it throws IOException
    obj2.method(); // it throws FileNotfoundException
}
```

The compiler would not complain. Why? Because for `obj1`, it throws an `IOException`, and that's fine, it's right there in the title, it can be thrown one level up. And for `obj2`, it knows that `FileNotFoundException` *is a* (type of) `IOException`, and therefore it is allowed to throw it. It is polymorphic with `IOException`, the caller will know what to do with it.

So the hierarchy of inheritance is important. If you have two methods that throw two exceptions, and one is a superclass of the other, you should declare your method to throw **the superclass**. Because any subclass has an "is_A" relationship with the superclass. It is a *specific* kind of the superclass. But the reverse is not true.

Answer (score 1):

You always throw the Exception and its subclasses, not the other way around (if that was the case, you would always throw Throwable).

Imagine MyException2 having a variable:

```
String name = "whatever";
```

Now if you throw an instance of MyException1, but somewhere else catch MyException2, it would go wrong because you cannot type cast from the more special class to its superclass. The field name is not present in MyException1.

The other way around will always work because MyException2 inherits all fields from MyException1.